# Recovering local storage from Firefox extension

Tags: sqlite, firefox, hex, binaryfiles

I'm trying to recover vault storage from MetaMask for Firefox on a broken Mac, but only have file system access so can't follow the usual recovery steps [here](https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018766351).

I've also tried copying the extension storage to a fresh install, but MetaMask won't launch.

On another computer, I've followed the usual recovery method linked to get a known-good export, which looks something like:

```
{
  ...
  "KeyringController": {
    "vault": "{\"data\":\"wLLUOXsS8u82TEDMjT1UNNtpANP2Eu6VfqbhHFTI3s+xKomLCXxnRtoPKlOlUDBPM7sOtIr8qoJofBqREfO9pN50vaEt3jw9sqUOk7Xdi0GHLpndlJvTmkI15aGk6udWc5MX/CW+F1KfJZbW7VpSMrrQPpfjULidxBLDfKac/wF9gF8pY4w1s9puVEgCgXAHYsX9bbR68vqMDLZmpr6NG5QCkFg0clLx6d6tddmMEg11hv+CrGI=\",\"iv\":\"8zjDMB77cQa1HX1B0gs+pQ==\",\"salt\":\"8VHAOfYllhPFs7zTgCr1PuZm7a4v8IFhoeqa2+7ZThQ=\"}"
  },
  ...
}
```

I've found the `idb` folder for the extension under `~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/profileid/storage/default/extensionid`, and dumped the main blob to file. Searching through this, I was able to find the vault part of the configuration:

```
0000ac70  72 69 6e 67 4e 5f 01 25  60 1e 40 14 2c 76 61 75  |ringN_.%`.@.,vau|
0000ac80  6c 74 00 00 00 55 01 00  00 0e d0 50 f4 02 02 7b  |lt...U.....P...{|
0000ac90  00 22 00 64 00 61 00 74  00 61 00 22 00 3a 00 22  |.".d.a.t.a.".:."|
0000aca0  00 77 00 4c 00 4c 00 55  00 4f 00 58 00 73 00 53  |.w.L.L.U.O.X.s.S|
0000acb0  00 38 00 75 00 38 00 32  00 54 00 45 00 44 00 4d  |.8.u.8.2.T.E.D.M|
0000acc0  00 6a 00 54 00 31 00 55  00 4e 00 4e 00 74 00 70  |.j.T.1.U.N.N.t.p|
0000acd0  00 41 00 4e 00 50 00 32  00 45 00 75 00 36 00 56  |.A.N.P.2.E.u.6.V|
0000ace0  00 66 00 71 00 62 00 68  00 48 00 46 00 54 00 49  |.f.q.b.h.H.F.T.I|
0000acf0  00 33 00 73 00 2b 00 78  00 4b 00 6f 00 6d 00 4c  |.3.s.+.x.K.o.m.L|
0000ad00  00 43 00 58 00 78 00 6e  00 52 00 74 00 6f 00 50  |.C.X.x.n.R.t.o.P|
0000ad10  00 4b 00 6c 00 4f 00 6c  00 55 00 44 00 42 00 50  |.K.l.O.l.U.D.B.P|
0000ad20  00 4d 00 37 00 73 00 4f  00 74 00 49 00 72 00 38  |.M.7.s.O.t.I.r.8|
0000ad30  00 71 00 6f 00 4a 00 6f  00 66 00 42 00 71 00 52  |.q.o.J.o.f.B.q.R|
0000ad40  00 45 00 66 00 4f 00 39  00 70 00 4e 00 35 00 30  |.E.f.O.9.p.N.5.0|
0000ad50  00 76 00 61 00 45 00 74  00 33 00 6a 00 77 00 39  |.v.a.E.t.3.j.w.9|
0000ad60  00 73 00 71 00 55 00 4f  00 6b 00 37 00 58 00 64  |.s.q.U.O.k.7.X.d|
0000ad70  00 69 00 30 00 47 00 48  00 4c 00 70 00 6e 00 64  |.i.0.G.H.L.p.n.d|
0000ad80  00 6c 00 4a 00 76 00 54  00 6d 00 6b 00 49 00 31  |.l.J.v.T.m.k.I.1|
0000ad90  00 35 00 61 00 47 00 6b  00 36 00 75 00 64 00 57  |.5.a.G.k.6.u.d.W|
0000ada0  00 63 00 35 00 4d 00 58  00 2f 00 43 00 57 00 2b  |.c.5.M.X./.C.W.+|
0000adb0  00 46 00 31 00 4b 00 66  00 4a 00 5a 00 62 00 57  |.F.1.K.f.J.Z.b.W|
0000adc0  00 37 00 56 00 70 00 53  00 4d 00 72 00 72 00 51  |.7.V.p.S.M.r.r.Q|
0000add0  00 50 00 70 00 66 00 6a  00 55 00 4c 00 69 00 64  |.P.p.f.j.U.L.i.d|
0000ade0  00 78 00 42 00 4c 00 44  00 66 00 4b 00 61 00 63  |.x.B.L.D.f.K.a.c|
0000adf0  00 2f 00 77 00 46 00 39  00 67 00 46 00 38 00 70  |./.w.F.9.g.F.8.p|
0000ae00  00 59 00 34 00 77 00 31  00 73 00 39 00 70 00 75  |.Y.4.w.1.s.9.p.u|
0000ae10  00 56 00 45 00 67 00 43  00 67 00 58 00 41 00 48  |.V.E.g.C.g.X.A.H|
0000ae20  00 59 00 73 00 58 00 39  00 62 00 62 00 52 00 36  |.Y.s.X.9.b.b.R.6|
0000ae30  00 38 00 76 00 71 00 4d  00 44 00 4c 00 5a 00 6d  |.8.v.q.M.D.L.Z.m|
0000ae40  00 70 00 72 00 36 00 4e  00 47 00 35 00 51 00 43  |.p.r.6.N.G.5.Q.C|
0000ae50  00 6b 00 46 00 67 00 30  00 63 00 6c 00 4c 00 78  |.k.F.g.0.c.l.L.x|
0000ae60  00 36 00 64 00 36 00 74  00 64 00 64 00 6d 00 4d  |.6.d.6.t.d.d.m.M|
0000ae70  00 45 00 67 00 31 00 31  00 68 00 76 00 2b 00 43  |.E.g.1.1.h.v.+.C|
0000ae80  00 72 00 47 00 49 00 3d  00 22 00 2c 00 22 00 69  |.r.G.I.=.".,.".i|
0000ae90  00 76 2d f8 10 38 00 7a  00 6a 25 e2 c8 42 00 37  |.v-..8.z.j%..B.7|
0000aea0  00 37 00 63 00 51 00 61  00 31 00 48 00 58 00 31  |.7.c.Q.a.1.H.X.1|
0000aeb0  00 42 00 30 00 67 00 73  00 2b 00 70 00 51 00 3d  |.B.0.g.s.+.p.Q.=|
0000aec0  00 3d 00 22 00 2c 00 22  00 73 00 61 00 6c 00 74  |.=.".,.".s.a.l.t|
0000aed0  15 44 f0 52 56 00 48 00  41 00 4f 00 66 00 59 00  |.D.RV.H.A.O.f.Y.|
0000aee0  6c 00 6c 00 68 00 50 00  46 00 73 00 37 00 7a 00  |l.l.h.P.F.s.7.z.|
0000aef0  54 00 67 00 43 00 72 00  31 00 50 00 75 00 5a 00  |T.g.C.r.1.P.u.Z.|
0000af00  6d 00 37 00 61 00 34 00  76 00 38 00 49 00 46 00  |m.7.a.4.v.8.I.F.|
0000af10  68 00 6f 00 65 00 71 00  61 00 32 00 2b 00 37 00  |h.o.e.q.a.2.+.7.|
0000af20  5a 00 54 00 68 00 51 05  6c 04 7d 00 19 01 61 70  |Z.T.h.Q.l.}...ap|
```

Reconstructing it, I was almost able to get the correct data but a few characters are incorrect:

```
data (extract): wLLUOXsS8u82TEDMjT1UNNtpANP2Eu6VfqbhHFTI3s+xKomLCXxnRtoPKlOlUDBPM7sOtIr8qoJofBqREfO9pN50vaEt3jw9sqUOk7Xdi0GHLpndlJvTmkI15aGk6udWc5MX/CW+F1KfJZbW7VpSMrrQPpfjULidxBLDfKac/wF9gF8pY4w1s9puVEgCgXAHYsX9bbR68vqMDLZmpr6NG5QCkFg0clLx6d6tddmMEg11hv+CrGI=
data (correct): wLLUOXsS8u82TEDMjT1UNNtpANP2Eu6VfqbhHFTI3s+xKomLCXxnRtoPKlOlUDBPM7sOtIr8qoJofBqREfO9pN50vaEt3jw9sqUOk7Xdi0GHLpndlJvTmkI15aGk6udWc5MX/CW+F1KfJZbW7VpSMrrQPpfjULidxBLDfKac/wF9gF8pY4w1s9puVEgCgXAHYsX9bbR68vqMDLZmpr6NG5QCkFg0clLx6d6tddmMEg11hv+CrGI=\

iv (extract): 8zj%B77cQa1HX1B0gs+pQ==
iv (correct): 8zjDMB77cQa1HX1B0gs+pQ==

salt (extract): DRVHAOfYllhPFs7zTgCr1PuZm7a4v8IFhoeqa2+7ZThQl
salt (correct): 8VHAOfYllhPFs7zTgCr1PuZm7a4v8IFhoeqa2+7ZThQ=\
```

Comparing the two IVs in hex, you can see how close they are but one nibble is missing, and one is incorrect:

```
correct: 38 7a 6a 44 4d 42 37 37 63 51 61 31 48 58 31 42 30 67 73 2b 70 51 3d 3d
extract: 38 7a 6a 25    42 37 37 63 51 61 31 48 58 31 42 30 67 73 2b 70 51 3d 3d
```

For the salt, the correct one is offset by one nibble and missing a couple:

```
correct:     38 56 48 41 4f 66 59 6c 6c 68 50 46 73 37 7a 54 67 43 72 31 50 75 5a 6d 37 61 34 76 38 49 46 68 6f 65 71 61 32 2b 37 5a 54 68 51 3d 5c
original: 44 52 56 48 41 4f 66 59 6c 6c 68 50 46 73 37 7a 54 67 43 72 31 50 75 5a 6d 37 61 34 76 38 49 46 68 6f 65 71 61 32 2b 37 5a 54 68 51 6c
```

Obviously the wallet above is now burned and won't be used, but any advice on how to repeat this for the recovered wallet would be really helpful.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Can you give a few pointers or more information on what to do in a similar case?